# On philosophies which morally empower society

Tags: ethics, human-condition

I see 4 possibilities when it comes to moral positions of a society as a response to the human condition and the moral code on how the moral philosophy spreads.

- **Moral authority**: for example, we subscribe to a notion of God and declare a spiritual text as the source of morals.
- **Amoral authority**: for example, citizens are expected to behave to norms regardless of ethics.
- **Amoral empowerment**: for example, all citizens are educated with the sciences, have ideas and are left to their own devices to form a moral ontology.
- **Moral empowerment**: for example, we take a detour and remember that Gandhi saw the struggle with the British as more of a problem with the human condition (other freedom fighters like Bhagat Singh did not). Gandhi's non-violence movement arguably morally empowered the British to realise their wrong doings. Notice, no moral authority was imposed on those who were disturbed by the discovery of their wrongdoings (and perhaps they had different moral codes of this realization).

Moral empowerment is when one  has a philosophy of ethics and it also includes a moral code to incentivize others to join it's philosophy.

### Question

What are some philosophies which morally empower the civilization? I can think of the  philosophy behind the [human revolution movement](https://www.sokaglobal.org/resources/study-materials/buddhist-concepts/human-revolution.html) and [Gandhism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandhism). What are some others?

Consider something like [absurdism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absurdism). I would argue absurdism is not moral empowerment because the philosophy does not have a moral code (or considers it to be optional) on how the philosophy should be spread.

Comment: For me it is totally unclear what you mean. What does mean “empowering a society”? What does mean to do it “morally”? “Who” empowers? Do you deal  with a question from ethics?

Comment: I mean "morally empower a society." What does to do it morally mean? Well  the answer to this would depend on which school of thought amongst the 4 you believe the human condition belongs to.

Comment: Who empowers? This assumes a mode of causality but it can be like inspiration where I say something and u paint the mona lisa. I could argue the outcome to be a synthesis between us.

Comment: I didn't understand the last question

Comment: How does your question relate to ethics, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics

Comment: Ethics or moral philosophy is a branch[1] of philosophy that "involves systematizing, defending, and recommending concepts of right and wrong behavior".

Comment: I have now categorised moral philosophy and in my question I ask which philosophies 'morally empower'

Comment: All 4 positions are responses of moral philosophy to the human condition

Comment: I think this is a promising question and I hope it is well received. I'll see if I can come up with an answer.

Comment: Does your phrase refer to this? [Moral Empowerment in education](https://philpapers.org/rec/FARMEI-2)

Comment: @ScottRowe this would be an example. A state where the citizens themselves discover their own philosophy and are incentivized by a moral code to continue to do so.

Comment: One may worry that they may come up with garbage but with a good education system and evolutionary reasons this seems unlikely

Comment: Ok. Any answer I can give would focus on the first step being: to recognize the pointlessness of ego and discursive thought, ultimately. I mean, Germany in the 1920s had a good education system.

Comment: I mean i thought Germany was amoral empowerment

Comment: I think though re-reading the writing it's difficult for someone who doesn't have this world view to get it

Comment: I say so because on the emphasis of "the sciences" ... We should be educated in the arts as well

Comment: Actually @ScottRowe would it be better if I asked is there a 4th position of moral empowerment?

Answer (score 1):

The principal obstacle to self-improvement is the self. Get that out of the way and everything else works fine. The endpoint of selflessness is Nonduality. There is a lot of material available on that, and historical figures like Nagarjuna are sometimes considered in Philosophical terms.  [The Center for the Study of Non-symbolic Consciousness](https://nonsymbolic.org) has been doing research for about a decade now.

There's an old joke that says, how do you tell if a politician is lying? His lips are moving. So, how do you tell if you are deluded? Your mind is moving. No, you can't persist in stillness all the time, but after reaching it, things look very different. No, you can't stay out of ego at all times, but after escaping it, the appeal of egoic behavior is dramatically lessened.

When ego and discursive thought become only sometimes useful tools instead of a continual, inescapable lifestyle, real improvement becomes possible, sustainable, easier. Otherwise I feel that real improvement of society is not going to happen because someone, somewhere will oppose it. And we will dither around not knowing what to do about that.

It is possible.